# cx_freeze not working with __init__ == __main__

Tags: python, exe

I have a strange problem. I am using cx_freeze to create executable file from python script. I have `setup.py` file with following code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable;

setup(name='Notebook',
      version='1',
      description='This is a Notebook.',
      executables=[Executable('menu.py')]);
```

and I execute this file with following command:

```
python setup.py build
```

I have several modules in my project. When I directly run my menu like this:

```
m = Menu()
m.run();
```

everything works fine. But when I use this check:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Menu()
    m.run();
```

.exe file just flashes. Can somebody help?
Sorry for English. Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Open a command line and call the exe file from there. Whatever problem it has, will be displayed in the console. BTW, why aren't you using `py2exe`?

Comment: "directly run" in a python shell? Or in the source file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using cx_Freeze 5.0 with Python 2.7, and I have exactly the same problem.

And it seems to be a regression since my script used to work with the previous version of cx_freeze (4.3.4).

To be more specific, I made an exe (not a GUI : base=None), and I put some print everywhere. I wrote a bat to call the exe.
All the prints are printed, except those which are in the "main section".

I also did the test with the sample SimpleTkApp.py delivered with cx_Freeze. The problem is the same: when the code is put in a main section, it doesn't work anymore : the exe is launched, then stopped, without doing nothing.

Comment: I have the same issue, it works with cx_freeze 4.3.4 but not with cx_freeze 5.0. I managed to get it to work by removing the if __ name __ == "__ main __" however this is not a fix

Answer (score 1):

I actually encountered the same problem recently, but I did manage to figure it out! It's because when you run the exe, its `__name__`  is not `__main__`, but something like `name_of_script__main__`. So in your case I'm pretty sure it would be `menu__main__`.

So, to figure out what your `__name__` actually is, you have to `print(__name__)` somewhere in the body of your code.